# Dynamic cron event system architecture

Tags: php, multithreading, apache

Our team was signed with the development of cron based event system. .

This means that a user can create data fields and then create events based on these fields.

For example I can add my clients table Birthday field and populate it with the date of birth of each of the clients.

Next I would go to the new event system and would create a rule which says that when do users birthday arrives send him an email.
The fields are on the one second resolution - dd:mm:yy hh:mm:ss.

I think it is impossible to where he did that the base every second in order to see if any event exists.

So my question is what is the best Architecture for something like this?

We are currently working on a LAMP stack.

I was thinking about polling every minute and creating a thread which will wait to the exact moment and then will execute the action, I am not very familiar with threads but m it sounds logical.

Is that a good implementation? Any better idea?
Would greatly appreciate an experienced advice .

Comment: You are working on LAMP, so I assume that the thread will be a child of Apache. What happen when the Apache is stopped or restarted? And, why don't you use `cron` OS?

Comment: I think you are correct and each thread will be a child of Apache. We are using php7-zts so I think it should be ok. I’m not sure what you are referring to As cron OS - do you mean using Linux core cron?

Comment: Yes, I mean the Linux core cron. Why don't you use it?

Comment: I’m not sure on how to output a command from php to cron (always used front abs for this). Can I just order cron from php to do something back from php?

Comment: I think, you may need: 1. a php file (like events.php) which will check  and execute if any event exists. 2. a `cron` which will call events.php every second. You should have a strategy to prevent the case when the second time runs when the first not yet finished. To register the `cron`, you may ask system admin or use `exec`, `shell_exec`,... function. Please note that you just need to register the `cron` only one time.

Comment: Thank you. Wouldn't it be more logical for example to see the list of tasks (query every minute / hour) and create a thread which sleeps until it's time?

Answer (score 1):

Could you please check "Command and Query Responsibility Segregation(CQRS)" architecture for your problem.